# Android device disconnect from adb when launching app from eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adb, device

I have a OnePlus X device, which I use with Eclipse for debugging my apps. I had a Nexus 4 which worked perfectly.

I have a late-2012 macbook pro, and I tried to plug my device directly in the usb port of the computer, and with an external alimented hub.

When I plug my OnePlus and I use the command "adb devices" I can see my device. Troubles comes when I run the Android app from eclipse... At this point, my device is disconnected and the app is not launched. And I can't see my device anymore with adb device. All I can do is restarting the adb server, but it will still disconnect after I tried to run the app in Eclipse

I tried different cables, different usb in, but nothing change.

Anyone has a solution ?

Comment: What about android studio?

Comment: I didn't try, but thing is that all my apps are under Eclipse and I just don't have the motivation to move everything right now...

Comment: You using USB 3 or 2?

Comment: I saw this answer form someone: `What worked for me was to run the app. When the window appeared to choose the device to run on (which was empty), I disconnected then reconnected the device, but before clicking to run, I checked the box (bottom left) to use this device for each run. It now runs every time directly on the device.`

Comment: I'm using USB3. I tried with Android Studio, but it shows the same error. Same problem with the method you describe.

Comment: Try USB 2.0, I was reading about 3.0 causing issues

Comment: I did, with no result, but thanks.